# Hide Print Option in Material UI Grid in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a bit old version of mui grid pro and I just wanted to hide the print option on the dropdown. I did add `printOptions={{ disableToolbarButton: true }}` but it still doesn't hide it.

Codesandbox: [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-sound-vj7q2j?file=/demo.js)

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarExport printOptions={{ disableToolbarButton: true }} />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
export default function RemovePrintExport() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPro
        loading={false}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar
        }}
        columns={[]}
        rows={[]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try it the way it is described in the documentation (via componentsProps)? https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#disabled-format

Comment: @ViktorG. Yes I tried that one too and its not working. You can fork my codesandbox to test it

Comment: @Joseph If I upgrade your sandbox to the latest version of the data grid (5.17.14), it works just fine. I assume that means the feature you are trying to use was added after the version in your sandbox.

Comment: @RyanCogswell. I intentionally used that old version. Is there a way to remove it via css?

Comment: @Joseph There might be some kludgy way to remove it via CSS, but the best option is to upgrade.

Comment: @RyanCogswell. Hi Ryan, I totally agree with you on the upgrade. but for now can you help me with modifying the css? Thank you